# Why is Maven connecting to archiva.openqa.org

Tags: maven

I'm building the code that I got from the book ActiveMQ in ACtion. When I run the code using these commands mvn clean install, I get these messages below. I cannot understand why it is downloading from release.openqa.org for the spring framework because I do not see anywhere in my POM.xml that this is configured to do so.

..........
Downloading from release.openqa.org: http://archiva.openqa.org/repository/releases/org/springframework/spring-core/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to release.openqa.org (http://archiva.openqa.org/repository/releases): Connect to archiva.openqa.org:80 [archiva.openqa.org/199.102.165.92] failed: Connection timed out: connect
.......

Content of POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <!--
    <parent> <groupId>org.apache.activemq.book</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-in-action</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> </parent>
  -->
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq.book</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-in-action-examples</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ActiveMQ in Action Examples</name>
  <description>ActiveMQ in Action Example Code</description>

  <!-- This build uses Maven 2.x -->

  <properties>
    <activemq-version>5.3.2</activemq-version>
    <camel-version>2.0.0</camel-version>
    <commons-logging-version>1.1</commons-logging-version>
    <commons-pool-version>1.4</commons-pool-version>
    <geronimo-spec-version>1.1</geronimo-spec-version>
    <junit-version>4.4</junit-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.14</log4j-version>
    <springframework-version>2.5.6</springframework-version>
    <stax-version>1.0.1</stax-version>
    <woodstox-version>3.2.7</woodstox-version>
    <xbean-version>3.4.3</xbean-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq-version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
          <artifactId>activeio-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>${geronimo-spec-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>${geronimo-spec-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-optional</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
      <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${xbean-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stax</groupId>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
      <version>${stax-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>woodstox</groupId>
      <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${woodstox-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-web</artifactId>
      <classifier>classes</classifier>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-logging-version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>logkit</groupId>
          <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>activemq-in-action-examples</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <source>1.5</source>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>example-src</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/activemq-in-action-src.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <name>java.net</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

After running mvn help:effective-pom, I get the following. I still do not see why maven is connecting to release.openqa.org:

```
PS C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src> mvn help:effective-pom
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.activemq.book:activemq-in-action-examples:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 155, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 163, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] --------< org.apache.activemq.book:activemq-in-action-examples >--------
[INFO] Building ActiveMQ in Action Examples 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:effective-pom (default-cli) @ activemq-in-action-examples ---
[INFO]
Effective POMs, after inheritance, interpolation, and profiles are applied:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Cp1252"?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2019-06-17T23:59:41+08:00            -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!-- 'org.apache.activemq.book:activemq-in-action-examples:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT' -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq.book</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-in-action-examples</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ActiveMQ in Action Examples</name>
  <description>ActiveMQ in Action Example Code</description>
  <properties>
    <activemq-version>5.3.2</activemq-version>
    <camel-version>2.0.0</camel-version>
    <commons-logging-version>1.1</commons-logging-version>
    <commons-pool-version>1.4</commons-pool-version>
    <geronimo-spec-version>1.1</geronimo-spec-version>
    <junit-version>4.4</junit-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.14</log4j-version>
    <springframework-version>2.5.6</springframework-version>
    <stax-version>1.0.1</stax-version>
    <woodstox-version>4.4.1</woodstox-version>
    <xbean-version>3.4.3</xbean-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>activeio-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-optional</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
      <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stax</groupId>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
      <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <classifier>classes</classifier>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
          <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
          <groupId>logkit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <name>java.net</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\target</directory>
    <finalName>activemq-in-action-examples</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>1.5</target>
              <source>1.5</source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>1.5</target>
              <source>1.5</source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <source>1.5</source>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>example-src</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src/src/main/assembly/activemq-in-action-src.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.162 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-17T23:59:51+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\munlai\websitepractice\ActiveMQ\source\amq-in-action-example-src>
```

Under the local repository C:\Users\wmunlai.m2\, I do see a few files called "resolver-status.properties". Could this be the cause? May I know the purpose of this file "resolver-status.properties". The content of one of this file is shown below:

```
#NOTE: This is a Maven Resolver internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Jun 17 23:58:04 SGT 2019
maven-metadata-apache.snapshots.xml.error=
maven-metadata-release.openqa.org.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata org.springframework\:spring/maven-metadata.xml from/to release.openqa.org (http\://archiva.openqa.org/repository/releases)\: Connect to archiva.openqa.org\:80 [archiva.openqa.org/199.102.165.92] failed\: Connection timed out\: connect
maven-metadata-java.net.xml.lastUpdated=1560787064788
maven-metadata-codehausSnapshots.xml/@default-codehausSnapshots-http\://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1560681286264
maven-metadata-java.net.m2.xml.lastUpdated=1560787065347
maven-metadata-release.openqa.org.xml/@default-release.openqa.org-http\://archiva.openqa.org/repository/releases/.lastUpdated=1560787084477
maven-metadata-java.net.xml.error=
maven-metadata-java.net.m2.xml.error=
maven-metadata-codehausSnapshots.xml.lastUpdated=1560686487495
maven-metadata-central.xml.lastUpdated=1560787063879
maven-metadata-apache.snapshots.xml.lastUpdated=1560787064417
```

It seems that this file camel-web-2.0.0.pom contains the following code that caused this problem:
C:\Users\wmunlai.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-web\2.0.0\camel-web-2.0.0.pom

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net.m2</id>
      <name>java.net Maven 2 Repo</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>release.openqa.org</id>
      <name>OpenQA Releases</name>
      <url>http://archiva.openqa.org/repository/releases</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repositories are either configured in the pom.xml file (your own one or a dependent one) or in settings.xml

You can check the effective files use by running `mvn help:effective-pom` or `mvn help:effective-settings`. The repo might appear there. Since spring dependencies are usually taken from central it might be a settings thing. Settings files can be placed into the maven installation directly or in your user home / .m2 directory or passed to the build with a parameter. So just add the help goals in front of your usual maven goals and then search for the repo name. If it's not showing up one of the dependencies you use may be a bit weird? Then I would search the local maven repository for that uri.

Adding repositories to pom.xml files is no longer encouraged, as they tend to move too frequent and impact the reliability of builds. Usually, companies install a repository mirror like Nexus or Artifactory. Both work by being configured as mirrorOf in settings.xml and proxy all requests made.

Comment: After running "mvn help:effective-pom", I still do not see why maven is connecting to release.openqa.org. I edited my question with the outputs from this command.

Comment: what about the settings search? or the search through the local maven repo?

Comment: Under the local repository C:\Users\wmunlai\.m2\, I do see a few files called "resolver-status.properties". Could this be the cause? May I know the purpose of this file "resolver-status.properties". The content of one of this file is shown above in my original post.

Comment: no, I think that file is just a result of the attempted resolution. You really should investigate all the settings locations first. Then verify no pom file in the local repo points to that uri. I really would think it needs to be in some .xml file.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is this file "C:\Users\wmunlai.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-web\2.0.0\camel-web-2.0.0.pom" contains the repository setting that points to release.openqa.org. I show the content in the my above post.

Comment: indeed that artifact seems to come with its own repositories until 2.9.0 https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-web/2.9.0/war - so you can only avoid that repo using a mirrorOf configuration and a repository proxy. The spring dependencies should be available on maven central so just make sure central is in your repo list as well. then it should be possible to make it work.